# how could i deal with the scores of the template matching techniques in cvMatchTemplate in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Becoz a rectangle [my used way to find the match] is drawn even when there is no proper match or no match

**I want the single match that is most accurate…**

is CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED the best one (i consider only accuracy)..??

Comment: Best method is to try yourself all options, and check which one is best for you.Gary Bradsky's "Learning OpenCV" has an example of template matching ,where he checks all the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a threshold, which is depending on your application.
I guess, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED returns 1 for a perfect match? (haven't tried it)
So maybe you can filter out false positives, if the global maximum is smaller than e.g. 0.8.